# Node serial port can not read data

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port, node-serialport

I am trying to read the data from arduino mega to my raspberry pi 3 through serial port. The node code:

```
const five = require("johnny-five")
const Raspi = require("raspi-io")
const SerialPort = require("serialport")
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline')


const arduinoSerialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", {
  baudRate: 9600
})
const parser = arduinoSerialPort.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }))

const board = new five.Board({
  io: new Raspi(),
  repl: false,
})


board.on('ready', function() {    
  parser.on('data', console.log)
})
```

arduino code:

```
int pushButton = 7;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pushButton, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);

  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    Serial.println('ononon');
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  }else{
    Serial.println('offfff');
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  }

  delay(100);
}
```

Arduino has a push button and and I am sending different data when the button is pushed or not.

On the node side I can't seem to read the data. All I get is some numbers.
I tried to use `toString()` did not work either.

I have been stuck here for long, some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you include the numbers that you see in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditional silly mistake :p

```
Serial.println('offfff');
```

C/C++ uses double quote sign `"` for string.

```
Serial.println("offfff");
```

Too much JavaScripting :v

Although in the arduino serial monitor I could see the line before so I did not think of looking into the arduino code.